# Java JNA with Windows CE, implementing .NET's MessageWindow equivalent

Tags: java, windows-ce, jna

I'm trying to make a java program to interact with a third-part DLL (I don't have that code)and receive window-based messages in Windows Mobile 6.5. I'm using JNA to achieve this. I can execute and read data from other methods in the DLL without any problem.

In C# i can make it work by extending MessageWindow class and overriding WndProc method

```css
internal class MyClass : MessageWindow
{
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
 {
  if (m.get_Msg() == 74)
  {
      doSomething(); 
  }
  base.WndProc(ref m);
 }
}
```

I wrote the same function in Java but it's not working

```css
//Finds the pointer to the Frame
INT_PTR winHandle = GetWindowHandle.findWindow(null,"MyFrame");
//Gets a pointer 
final LONG_PTR prevWndProc = new LONG_PTR(CoreDll.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(new HWND(winHandle.toPointer()), -4).longValue());
//CallbackProc implements Callback and StdCallback
CallbackProc ptr=new CallbackProc() {
    @Override
    public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == 74)
    {
      doSomething();
    }
    return CoreDll.INSTANCE.CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
};
CoreDll.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(winHandle,-4 ,ptr);
```

I researched on the web several hours and I haven't found anything helpful. If anyone can give me some hint I will really appreciate it.

Best Regards

EDIT

I edited my code to the following:

```css
//Finds the pointer to the Frame
INT_PTR winHandle = GetWindowHandle.findWindow(null,"MyFrame");
//Gets a pointer 
final LONG_PTR prevWndProc = new LONG_PTR(CoreDll.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(new HWND(winHandle.toPointer()), -4).longValue());
HWND Hwnd=new HWND(winHandle.toPointer());
//CallbackProc implements Callback and StdCallback
CallbackProc ptr=new CallbackProc() {
    @Override
    public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == 74)
    {
      doSomething();
    }
    else if (uMsg == 2828)
    {
      stop=true;
    }
    return CoreDll.INSTANCE.CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
};
CoreDll.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(winHandle,-4 ,ptr);
new Thread() {
      public void run() {
          fireMsgWndEvent(0,"Run!");
          while (!stop) {
                    try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(Exception e) { }
                }
                fireMsgWndEvent(0,"Stopped!");
            }
        }.start();
        
int result;
MSG msg = new MSG();
while ((result = CoreDll.INSTANCE.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
 if (result == -1) {
   System.err.println("error in get message");
    break;
}
else {
    System.err.println("got message");
    CoreDll.INSTANCE.TranslateMessage(msg);
    CoreDll.INSTANCE.DispatchMessage(msg);
}
}
```

But still didn't get any luck with it, I'm not receiving any message, please help me :'(

Comment: 1) What's it supposed to do? 2) What does it do instead?

Comment: 1) Read data using LParam after a "Msg() == 74" is received in WndProc 2) After researching on the web I read that MessageWindow provides the ability to send and receive Windows-based messages, but I can't acomplish that using Java. It just doesn't receive anything but in .NET it works fine

Comment: Where do you set the window to use your window procedure?

Comment: You likely need to run your own message pump with `GetMessage()/DispatchMessage()`.  There is an example of this in the [JNA low-level keyboard hook example](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java#L67).

Comment: @technomage I've followed the example in [link](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java#L67) but still I'm not able to receive any message, I've edited my post with the modified code

Comment: @immibis i forgot to paste that line of code in this post, i edited my code with some modifications in this post, can you see what I'm missing? thanks

Comment: Wait, why are you sending window messages to yourself?

Comment: @immibis You're totally right, thanks, I've changed it to GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0) but still didn't getting any message though

Comment: @JoseMSan Not what I meant - is there some other program sending you window messages or is it just your own program?

Comment: @immibis I'm using a DLL that is sending messages but I don't know how to refer to the DLL thread

Comment: @technomage should I implement my own GetMessage()/DispatchMessage()?

Comment: Your example should work fine, although you should run it on a daemon thread rather than inline.